# Does the MySQL workbench show uncommitted changes?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, mysql-workbench, rollback

Why does the MySQL workbench show uncommitted changes?

```
-- create a new empty table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS X;
CREATE TABLE X (val varchar(10));

-- disable autocommit
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;

-- insert a row without committing
INSERT INTO X (val) VALUES ('text');
```

At this point

```
SELECT @@autocommit, @@tx_isolation;
```

returns

| 0 | REPEATABLE-READ |

However, a query shows the value which has not yet been committed:

```
SELECT * FROM X;
```

| text |

**Why does MySQL return a result set with uncommitted data?**

If I roll back the transaction using

```
ROLLBACK;
```

then MySQL returns an empty table when querying X. (That confirms that the transaction hasn't been committed automatically at some point of time.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL workbench and is what Transaction/Commit means. ALL SQL servers does this. The point is that you HAVE inserted the new value, just that you HAVEN'T commited the change.

Comment: Ok, but the isolation level "repeatable read" is higher than the "read committed" level. Why can I see the uncommitted change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I am always in the same transaction (regardless the window tab).